# Update an excel sheet uploaded in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-5, upload

I have a function where an excel sheet is uploaded and cells are read using column names which match the item in a list of string in the backend.
I need to alter the column names ( remove spaces and convert to lower()) so that it matches the items when I use the list of string as column names to read the excel sheet.

I am using IExcelDataReader Library from nuget package .
I read all the column names using this package and looped through them  trying to alter them but I couldn't do so as it was a read only mode.

What can I do to alter the column names of an uploaded excel sheet.

```
          public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
          {
              if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Stream stream = upload.InputStream;
                    IExcelDataReader reader = null;
                    if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") || upload.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        var file = upload.FileName;
                        reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
                        var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
                        {
                            ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
                            {
                                UseHeaderRow = true
                            }
                        };
                        var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);                            

                        var Model = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows;
                        var meta = listOfStrings; // Column names to be read in a list 
                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                                foreach (var item in meta)
                                {
                                    dict.Add(item, Model[i][item.ToLower().Trim()].ToString());
                                    // During this stage I need the column names to exactly match my list of string                         
                                   // What can I do to Convert my strings to lower case and trim them?
                                }
                             }
                    }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors or just dont know how to do what youre asking?

Comment: I tried altering the column names by fetching all the column names through excel data reader and looping through it but I couldn't because it was in read only mode.

Comment: So I need another way to do this. I don't know how to do it

Comment: ok, can you edit your question, to detail exactly what you are trying to do, and what the issues \ errors you are finding.  include what libraries you are using to help anyone else trying to help you.

Comment: Is this the one and have you read the documentation? https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: also, what namespace is ExcelDataSetConfiguration in

Comment: Hey I think I found another way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: According to my requirement I don't have to edit the column names. Just create a temporary string and do the comparisons on this string

Comment: It would be helpful to others for you to post your answer so that this isnt just left as a dead question and enable you to help others too